# How to open gnome terminal via crontab

Tags: command-line, gnome, cron

I want to open gnome-terminal after Ubuntu boots up.

Added these lines to crontab:

```
DISPLAY=:0
@reboot gnome-terminal --maximize
```

After Ubuntu boots up terminal is opened but not fully operational.

I can see this at the top:

```
-sh: 24: [[: not found
$
```

Seems that something was not loaded.

Any ides what may be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is used for running things that don't need to provide a user interface. You need GNOME Terminal to provide a user interface.

It would be better to add it as a startup application:

1. Go to the dash
2. Run `Startup Applications`
3. Click `Add`
4. For `Name`: `Maximized terminal`
5. For `Command`: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --maximize`
6. For `Comment`: `Starts GNOME Terminal maximized`
7. Click `Add`
8. Click `Close`